# Consulta SQL para hacer un salto de línea

Tags: sql-server, sql

pues la cosa es que me estaba preguntando si al valor de una columna de `SQL` se le puede agregar un salto de línea. A modo de ejemplo:

**Campo:** Detalle

**Valor del campo:** Juan tiene cinco años. Mañana cumple seis.

**La consulta es:**

```
SELECT Detalle FROM tablaEjemplo
```

Quiero saber si existe alguna forma de que se pueda ver así:

```
Juan tiene cinco años.
Mañana cumple seis.
```

Comment: El único patrón que podrías usar, es el punto o el punto más el espacio: `SELECT REPLACE(Detale, '. ', '.' + CHAR(10)) FROM tablaEjemplo`

Comment: O sea que al valor: `Juan tiene cinco años. Mañana cumple seis`, no le puedo poner un salto de línea luego del primer punto @PatricioMoracho

Comment: Aunque depende un poco de dónde quieras ver el salto de línea. En el cliente en el que haces el query? En una aplicación web? CHAR(10) hace que el cliente muestre el contenido de la columna Detalle con el salto de línea, pero no es evidente que eso es lo que quieras. Y lo que te están diciendo del punto es que necesitas identificar un patrón en el String de `Detalle` para que REPLACE cambie ese patrón por patrón+saltoDeLínea

Comment: Si, esa es la idea del `replace` remplazar el punto más el espacio por un punto más un salto de línea, eso puede funcionar como puede que no, no siempre los puntos son separadores de oraciones

Comment: muchísimas gracias @PatricioMoracho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, como te dijeron anteriormente, puedes lograr saltos de linea manipulando la cadena, obvio, en un select no lo apreciaras pero en un print, editor de texto o aplicación es posible evidenciar.

Por ejemplo:
Si haces un un select solo se ve una linea:

```
select 'hola'+char(10) + char(13) + 'mundo'
```

Pero haciendo un print, lo puedes visualizar:

```
print 'hola'+char(10) + char(13) + 'mundo'
```

Saludos

Comment: Claro, pero si yo tengo el texto en el valor de una columna, ¿Cómo lo hago? A ver, yo tengo almacenado el valor en el campo Detalle de la tabla Ejemplo, entonces quiero saber ¿Cómo hago para poner el salto de línea al valor dentro del campo Detalle?

Comment: Si sabes donde estan los elemenos que rompen lineas, claro que es posible.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que manipular el string que te devuelve el SQL. O si no, guardar el valor en la tabla con el código de salto de línea. Así al imprimir el resultado en pantalla saldrá con el salto de línea.

Comment: Claro, pero si yo tengo el texto en el valor de una columna, ¿Cómo lo hago? A ver, yo tengo almacenado el valor en el campo Detalle de la tabla Ejemplo, entonces quiero saber ¿Cómo hago para poner el salto de línea al valor dentro del campo Detalle?

Comment: Depende de con qué lenguaje vayas a interpretar el resultado. Por ejemplo si es HTML, con <br /> o si es PHP, pues con \n